# PostgreSQL: return entries where value in column A shows multiple time for distinct values in column B

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Imagine the table:

```
col_A     col_B   
banana      1     
apple       1
banana      45     
banana      1     
kiwi        2
grape       2
grape       33
strawberry  56
strawberry  56
```

I would like to return:

```
col_A    col_B
banana    1
banana    45
grape     2
grape     33
```

I can't think of a way or a function to obtain this result. Hoping for recommendations.

Comment: You miss `strawberry 56`. Is it indeed?

Comment: No. Strawberry returns the same value for col_B. I'm interested in returning those entries where col_A value shows multiple times for different values in col_B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in postgre sql

> Schema Definition

```
CREATE TABLE test_dp (
  "firsttt" VARCHAR(10),
  "secondd" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test_dp
  ("firsttt", "secondd")
VALUES
  ('banana', '1'),
  ('apple', '1'),
  ('banana', '45'),
  ('banana', '1'),
  ('kiwi', '2'),
  ('grape', '2'),
  ('grape', '33'),
  ('strawberry', '56'),
  ('strawberry', '56');
```

> Query

```
select 
  distinct(dp1.*) 
from 
  test_dp dp1 
  inner join test_dp dp2 on dp1.firsttt = dp2.firsttt
  and dp1.secondd <> dp2.secondd;
```

[DB Fiddle UK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=03ba5ab63d361b94bfd16ad635d01604)

Comment: Thanks. However, this still returns all entries and not the desired return shown in the question.

Comment: select 
  distinct(dp1.*) 
from 
  test_dp dp1 
  inner join test_dp dp2 on dp1.firsttt = dp2.firsttt
  and dp1.secondd <> dp2.secondd;

Comment: @Joehat This should get you your desired output. I didnt understand the question at first

Comment: @Joehat I have edited the query in my post.

Comment: that's exactly it! Thank you. Would you mind telling me the keywords or share links to find more about what you've done? - I want to understand why dp1 and dp2 should be there.

Comment: dp1 and dp2 are table aliases to reference the same table but two different instances of it. In this we have created a self join. I recommend you read a book on SQL to understand joins and subqueries. It will make your job a 1000x easier.